# Arithmetic with pandas objects

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to calculate the difference between two Pandas series in Python. Unfortunately, an error, which I cannot make sense of, is returned. The relevant part of my code is:

```
import urllib.request 
import pandas as pd 

base_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="

def get_data(base_url,ticker):
    url = base_url + ticker
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return  pd.read_csv(source,index_col=0,parse_dates=True,header=None)

ticker_list = {'INTC': 'Intel'}

for ticker in ticker_list:
    prices = get_data(base_url,ticker)
    prices.columns = 'Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adj Close'
    closing_prices = prices['Close']
    begin = closing_prices.ix[['2013-01-03']]
    end = closing_prices.ix[['2013-12-27']]
    difference = end.sub(begin)
```

Python returns the following error:

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

However, `type(begin)` returns `pandas.core.series.Series` as does `type(end)`. I used the method `end.sub()` because I thought I wanted to adhere to the instruction stated here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html. For trying to address my problem, I (among other things) followed the following recommendations: [Subtract a column from one pandas dataframe from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100717/subtract-a-column-from-one-pandas-dataframe-from-another) to no avail.

Do you have any idea where the mistake is buried in my code? In particular, why does Python state that I try to subtract strings?  I am grateful for any help!

**Update**: Following @EdChum's comment I would like to post some data: typing `begin` gives:

```
`2013-01-03    21.32
 Name: Close, dtype: object
```

`closing_prices.head()` gives:

```
`0
Date          Close
2014-08-07    32.68 
2014-08-06    32.85
2014-08-05    32.82
2014-08-04    34.05
Name: Close, dtype: object`
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the values inside the Series (`begin` and `end`)? Try `begin.dtype` (or just print the series)

Comment: `begin.dtype` returns `dtype('O')`

Comment: `df.info()` or `df.dtypes`

Comment: Print `begin`, or `begin.values`. There will probably be a string in it.

Comment: Are your dates strings rather than datatimes? you can convert them using `df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])` or if it's the index `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: @joris: I think you are right. `begin.values` returns `array(['21.32'], dtype=object)`. The '21.32' indicates that the price is stored as a string? How can I change this?

Comment: You'd have to convert them, not sure if [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) can handle this, otherwise you'd have to something like `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: float(x[0]))`

Comment: @EdChum: For your second post: If I type (replacing `df` with `begin`)  `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` and then `end.sub(begin)` a modified error is returned: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'`. When typing `df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])` I receive the error: `KeyError: 'col'`. Probably I am doing something wrong in the implementation of your suggestion.

Comment: You have to post some data, the problem here is that your data are not integers or floats or datetimes so subtraction makes little sense. I've posted various ways to convert the dtype to datetime or floats so you should be able to fix this. At the moment it's difficult for me to reproduce your error, you'll need to print some data and see what the dtypes are and fix them

Comment: @EdChum: For your third post: Isn't there something wrong in the way I retrieve the data? Can't I tackle the problem earlier on before doing such kind of conversion?

Comment: yes you could specify the dtype param in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), also if you know the column that is a date then you could set this too `parse_dates=[0]` where first column is a date col

Comment: @EdChum: Following your fourth post, I edited my initial question - thank you!

Comment: Please post output from `df.info()` and `df.dtypes`

Comment: `df.info()` gives `'Series' object has no attribute 'info'` and `df.dtypes` gives `dtype('O')`

Comment: I think the issue may be with the csv header. The data you're downloading already contains the headers. Maybe remove `header=None`?

Comment: @DataSwede: When doing this `df.dtypes` gives a float64 variable. But `end.sub(begin)` still returns `2013-01-03   NaN
2013-12-27   NaN
Name: Close, dtype: float64`(dtype changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change urllib to urllib2, and urllib.request.urlopen to just urllib2.urlopen.. But, it should otherwise be the same. The first issue was caused by having the column names stored as a value. Eliminating the `header=None` fixes that.

This should give you the difference between the first and last date specified:

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd 

base_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="

def get_data(base_url,ticker):
    url = base_url + ticker
    source = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return  pd.read_csv(source,index_col=0,parse_dates=True)

ticker_list = {'INTC': 'Intel'}
```

**EDIT**- Be sure to check the sorting of the data.. It places the newest at the top, the oldest at the bottom for me.

```
for ticker in ticker_list:
    prices = get_data(base_url,ticker)
    prices.columns = 'Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adj Close'
    closing_prices = prices['Close']
    closing_prices = closing_prices['2013-01-03':'2013-12-27']
    difference = closing_prices['2013-12-27'].values - closing_prices['2013-01-03'].values
    print difference
```

Comment: thank you! Your method worked (except changing `print(difference)`. But I wonder what is wrong with the `series.sub()` method. Do you have any idea why `closing_prices['2013-12-27'].values - closing_prices['2013-01-03'].values` works while `difference = end.sub(begin)` does not work?

Comment: I think the sub functionality requires a matching index. Meaning, if you wanted to subtract low from high (each a different series), and line up the exact days. In your case, the indexes will not match, since they are two different days. Though, I very well could be wrong..

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more complicated than it really is: you'll need to convert `end` end `begin` to numeric data types. Try [DataFrame.convert_objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects):

```
...
begin = begin.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
end = end.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
difference = end.sub(begin)
```

Update: The following code works for me:

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd 

base_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="

def get_data(base_url,ticker):
    url = base_url + ticker
    source = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return  pd.read_csv(source,index_col=0,parse_dates=True,header=None)

ticker_list = {'INTC': 'Intel'}

for ticker in ticker_list:
    prices = get_data(base_url,ticker)
    prices.columns = 'Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adj Close'

    # this will convert the closing_prices Series to float
    closing_prices = prices['Close'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

    # changed the double square brackets [[]] to single square brackets to
    # obtain a scalar, rather than a single element Series
    begin = closing_prices.ix['2013-01-03']
    end = closing_prices.ix['2013-12-27']
    difference = end - begin
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With your suggestion `difference = end.sub(begin)` still return the same NaN error. However, using `end.values - begin.values` gives me the right solution. Do you have any idea why the `sub()` method does not work? I thought this is what Pandas instructs us to do.

Comment: Your problem, which I hadn't initially realized, is that you're trying to subtract two scalars, not two vectors. The `sub` method requires the two Series to be aligned (ie, the indexes are the same). I've updated my answer to explain this better.