# Subtract multiple columns based on foreign key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the difference between an object and it's benchmark. I have a dataset containing daily records for all of the objects and their corresponding values that looks like this:

```
obj_df
date         id   value_a value_b value_c value_d  benchmark_id
01/21/2015  abc        10      41      19      22           efg
01/22/2015  abc        15      43      11      21           efg
01/21/2015  xyz        16      45      13      26           tuv
01/22/2015  xyz        13      48      12      22           tuv
01/21/2015  tru        10      39      15      21           efg
01/21/2015  tru        11      37      13      20           efg
```

I also have the data about the benchmarks. The value columns are shared between dataframes. The id in the benchmark set corresponds to a benchmark id in the original object dataframe.

```
bm_df
date         id   value_a value_b value_c value_d
01/21/2015  efg        12      40      12      20
01/22/2015  efg        15      41      14      21
01/21/2015  tuv        14      42      11      19
01/22/2015  tuv        13      43      19      17
```

I'm trying to find a simple way to return a dataframe that gives me the difference between the object values and the corresponding benchmark value to get a dataframe that looks something like this.

```
diff_df
date         id    diff_a  diff_b  diff_c  diff_d benchmark_id
01/21/2015  abc        -2       1       7       2          efg
01/22/2015  abc         0       2      -3       0          efg
01/21/2015  xyz         2       3       2       7          tuv
01/22/2015  xyz         0       5      -7       5          tuv
01/21/2015  tru        -4      -3       4       2          efg
01/21/2015  tru        -2      -6      -6       3          efg
```

A few things to note:
 - There are more objects than benchmarks, so the indexes will not be the same size.
 - Every object has a benchmark.
 - I don't particularly care about the original values. Just the difference.
 - Some benchmarks correspond to more than one object. For example both 'abc' and 'tru' use 'efg' as the benchmark.

Comment: This link seems like it got pretty close to what I'm trying to do:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100717/subtract-a-column-from-one-pandas-dataframe-from-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Steps:***

Perform merge:

```
df = obj_df.merge(bm_df, left_on=['benchmark_id', 'date'], right_on=['id', 'date'])    \
           .drop(['id_y'], 1).set_index(['date'])
```

Helper function to find column index locations by inputting the starting and ending column names:

```
def col_locate(df, start, end):
    start_loc = df.columns.get_loc(start)
    end_loc = df.columns.get_loc(end)
    return list(range(start_loc, end_loc+1))

fir, sec = col_locate(df,'value_a_x','value_d_x'), col_locate(df,'value_a_y','value_d_y')
```

Subtract the values from the `objectDF`and the `benchmarkDF`:

```
df_diff = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, fir].values - df.iloc[:, sec].values, 
                       columns=list('abcd'), index=df.index).add_prefix('diff_')
```

Finally, Concatenate them columnwise:

```
pd.concat([df[['id_x', 'benchmark_id']], df_diff], axis=1)
```

[image]

***Note:*** Updated `DF` used to arrive at the result.

Comment: The solution you provide needed some modifications to run. It also has a few issues.
  
1) The column indexes should be [2:6] and [6:] to accommodate benchmark id and due to non-overlapping index ranges.  
2)The new dataframe column names do not reflect that the new columns are differences and not the original values  
3) This assumes that column order is guaranteed, which is not necessarily true in my use case, although not specified explicitly in the question.

Comment: *see edit*. I've updated my post which doesn't take the column order into account. If you know the starting and ending column names of each `DF`, you can get this to work is my blind guess.

Comment: I made some slight modifications for my own use case, but I think this sufficiently answers the posted question.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html), then add columns `id` and `benchmark_id` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) columns to same order as columns of `obj_df`:

```
print (obj_df) 
                value_a  value_b  value_c  value_d benchmark_id
date       id                                                  
01/21/2015 abc       10       41       19       22          efg
01/22/2015 abc       15       43       11       21          efg
01/21/2015 xyz       16       45       13       26          tuv
01/22/2015 xyz       13       48       12       22          tuv

print (bm_df)
                value_a  value_b  value_c  value_d
date       id                                     
01/21/2015 efg       12       40       12       20
01/22/2015 efg       15       41       14       21
01/21/2015 tuv       14       42       11       19
01/22/2015 tuv       13       43       19       17
```

```
obj_df.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)
bm_df.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)
cols = ['value_a','value_b','value_c', 'value_d']
df = obj_df[cols].sub(bm_df[cols])
df = pd.concat([df, obj_df[['id','benchmark_id']]], axis=1)
       .reindex(columns=obj_df.columns)
       .reset_index()

print (df)
         date   id  value_a  value_b  value_c  value_d benchmark_id
0  01/21/2015  abc       -2        1        7        2          efg
1  01/22/2015  abc        0        2       -3        0          efg
2  01/21/2015  xyz        2        3        2        7          tuv
3  01/22/2015  xyz        0        5       -7        5          tuv
```

Comment: I think you need `obj_df = obj_df.reset_index(level=1)
bm_df = bm_df.reset_index(level=1)` before.

Answer (score 3):

```
odf = obj_df.set_index(['date', 'benchmark_id'])
bdf = bm_df.set_index(['date', 'id'])

odf.update(odf.drop('id', 1).sub(bdf))
odf.reset_index().reindex_axis(obj_df.columns, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This spits back this error:
NotImplementedError: merging with both multi-indexes is not implemented

Comment: @jezrael. The solution you posted also gave me this error. The issue may be an issue on my end. Any ideas?

Comment: @Charles if updating pandas is an option, then do that.  Otherwise, you'll have to tell us what version you're running so we know what we can and cannot do.

Comment: this worked with the dummy data that I gave in the question, so I'm marking it as correct. That being said, when I try to apply it to the real data I'm working on (which has the same structure), I get the NotImplementedError. Do you have any clue why that may be the case?

Specifically, it breaks on 
    odf.sub(bdf)

Comment: I can't see what's throwing the error.  You can find the subset of data that produces the break and post that as sample data.

Comment: I found the problem. This process breaks when a benchmark applies to more than one object. For example if objects ['abc', 'qrs', 'tru'] all use benchmark 'efg'. It will break.

If we can solve this, I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use merge:

```
#inner join on FK
merge = obj_df.merge(bm_df, left_on = 'benchmark_id', right_on = 'id', suffixes = ['_obj', '_bm'])
#create new columns
for value in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    merge.loc[:, 'diff_%s'%value] = merge['value_%s_obj'%value] - merge['value_%s_bm'%value]
```